# how can i use mysql on a facebook group

Tags: php, facebook

i wanted to know if it was possible to get for example the people who post the most in a facebook group in which i'm the admin Using mysql to retrieve those information
thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use the Facebook API?

Comment: Short answer: No. Use the Facebook Graph API. MySQL can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the group feed endpoint and go through every post on your own. There is example code and a detailed description in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/feed

For example:

- Use the feed endpoint to get the latest entries.
- Store them in a database (for caching) and check if the entries are already in there.
- Use paging to get more entries, if one batch is not in the database: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging
- Check who creates the most posts with your language of choice by just going through your database entries.

Problem: You would need to handle comments too, not just posts. That is where it gets tricky, because you would need to re-check every post for new comments - or just newer ones.

Comment: it seems kinda complicated , would you wanna give me who posts the most if i send you the group's link ? 
that would be very kind of you
thanks for your reply

Comment: not sure what you expect from me, to be honest. you need to program something to do that...i am up for hire, if you want to pay me for creating an app, but stackoverflow is strictly for "dev2dev" help.